# Real time events show up with a 4 minute delay

Tags: clock

So I just bought a Milestone 2 and installed CM 7.2 by Endless (based on the Defy CM ROM). Everything is working great, but there's one thing that annoys me.

Everytime I tweet something it never shows up as `x secs ago`, instead it shows `4 min ago`.

This also happens on the Facebook app. The real time events always shows 4 minutes. It is like the OS is adding the time by itself. This really doesn't make much difference but I'm really curious as it why does it happens. Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your clock is 4 minutes fast.   Check to see if your phone is getting its time from the network (on Gingerbread, it's Settings/Date & Time, not sure about CM 7.2).

If you are getting time from the network, try disabling automatic updates and set the time manually to a source like time.gov or time.is.